# Posso postar links de páginas interessantes no SOpt?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Existe uma maneira de publicar links interessantes, como cursos ou eventos para que todos possam ver?

Caso não exista esse recurso, poderia ter ? Acho legal.

Comment: No chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha podes.

Comment: Ou na wiki da Tag

Comment: Não sei fazer isso @brasofilo.

Comment: Esse link que fornece leva para um lugar que fala em promo codes e $$$ para desbloquear conteúdo. O que exatamente é "legal" ou "top"? O vídeo do YouTube? A sugestão de wiki de tags não é pra poluir com esse tipo de coisa. Valeu!  http://i.stack.imgur.com/78yqH.png

Comment: O link que você disse que é legal é simplesmente *muito estranho* e tinha um promocode que removi pois não vinha ao caso e pode ser considerado spam. Pode explicar o que tem de *top* nesse link?

Comment: "link interessante" é diferente de "link comercial".. Acho que não deveria permitir propaganda gratuita desses serviços. Mas quem deve decidir , acho que é a administração da empresa que mantem o Stack.

Comment: Não é diferente. Um LINK comercial pode ser interessante. Cardinalidade de categoria.

Comment: Não importa se a pessoa que publica não ganha nada e publicou apenas por gostar ou achar interessante pois, caracteriza-se como propaganda de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pra ampliar a dica do [@brasofilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4334/posso-postar-links-de-p%C3%A1ginas-interessantes-no-sopt#comment13422_4334)

> **Nota:** Mas precisa tomar cuidado com o que coloca. Tem que ser algo reconhecidamente bom. Começar colocar um repositório de links sem qualidade atestada ali só vai fazer o recurso ficar imprestável. E principalmente não pode ser spam. Tem que ser algo que dificilmente ficará invalidado. –  bigown

Quando você faz uma pesquisa por tag por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel

Aparece no topo da página isto (link *saiba mais*):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Clicando nele vai abrir um link como este https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info

Nele tera um botão chamado Editar Wiki:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Clicando nele terá dois campos:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

O primeiro campo de texto e o fragmento, use-o somente para uma descrição rápida e intuitiva, já o segundo é o que usamos para editar ou criar o "Wiki da tag"

Nele você pode colar links interessantes e úteis a tag, ou seja **tome cuidado** com o que irá postar.

Comment: Com fundo branco, realmente.

Comment: Vê se assim quebra um galho

Comment: Mas precisa tomar cuidado com o que coloca. Tem que ser algo reconhecidamente bom. Começar colocar um repositório de *links* sem qualidade atestada ali só vai fazer o recurso ficar imprestável. E principalmente não pode ser *spam*. Tem que ser algo que dificilmente ficará invalidado.

Comment: @bigown entao, foi isto que eu quis dizer com "Nele voce pode colar links interessantes e uteis a tag." Mas talvez realmente nao tenha ficado tao claro.

Comment: O problema é que fica muito no julgamento da pessoa. Por exemplo, o *link* da pergunta é ruim para colocar em uma *tag*. A qualidade não é comprovada, pode não existir ou mudar a situação a qualquer momento, mesmo que não seja a intenção beira a *spam*. Mas o AP acha interessante, então ele poderia ir lá e colocar.

Comment: @bigown poderia ter um dia por mes de faxina - Rollback, rollback, rollback :)

Comment: Na prática isto não funciona.

Comment: @bigown por isso que disse que teria o mes pra fazer faxina, mas realmente nao tem algo muito automatizado, o bom e que poucos usuarios podem editar diretamente e tem que passar por aprovacao.

Comment: @Math ficou otimo, nem pensei nisto, obrigado!

Comment: Por isso que eu acho que não pode aprovar qualquer coisa, como às vezes acontece. Tem o pessoal que só clica no botão pra ganhar medalha.

Comment: E um dos males de como funciona os sites do StackExchange infelizmente @bigown , de qualquer maneira editei um pouco a resposta.

Comment: Massa :) Vim aqui responder e já tá belezinha, jejej @DiegoSouza, eu "adotei" esta tag: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress/info

Comment: @brasofilo um excelente exemplo de colaboração adotar uma tag :) Parabéns, vou seguir o exemplo. (nota: Gostei do uso do `<kbd>`)